# toaster yocto build UI

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to write my own UI based yocto build.  But i am not getting clue how the hob/toaster project is able to show the console output in screen.
For example, if receipes are parsed its displayed in the progress bar.  Also i am not much aware of python code, to look much more on toaster source code.

My findings:
1.  There is a log directory getting created for every bitbake build(as per the bitbake.conf file).  I am able to read the log file.  But i am not exactly sure did the toaster/hob follow the same procedure.

Any help is appreciated.